# Elixir: bad argument in arithmetic expression al tratar de sumar

Tags: elixir

estoy tratando de acer un programa que me regrese la [secuencia de collatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) en Elixir, pero obtengo un feo error que dice

> 1) test a few basic test cases (CollatzTest)
>
> ```
>  test/solution_test.exs:4
>
>  ** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
>
>  code: assert Collatz.collatz(3) == "3->10->5->16->8->4->2->1"
>
>  stacktrace:
>
>    (solution) lib/solution.ex:7: Collatz.collatz/1
>
>    (solution) lib/solution.ex:8: Collatz.collatz/1
>
>    (solution) lib/solution.ex:10: Collatz.collatz/1
>
>    test/solution_test.exs:7: (test)
> ```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
defmodule Collatz do

  def collatz(n) do
    cond do
      n == 1 ->
        "1"
      rem(n,2) == 0 ->
        "#{n}->#{collatz(n/2)}"
      true ->
        "#{n}->#{collatz(n*3+1)}"
    end
  end

end
```

¿A qué se debe mi error y cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debía a que en algún momento de las llamadas recursivas dejaba de trabajar con enteros, la solución es forzarlo a permanecer en el reino de los enteros, la solución más explícita que pude hallar es redondear el resultado para que permanezca como entero.

```
round(n/2)
```